# Belkin router not working properly

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I found my old router **Belking54g** and it works with no problem.

But when I try to visit the router site (`192.168.2.1`) it works, but to make changes, such as set the SSID and router's password I have to login.

I click <kbd>Login</kbd> or any other button it always opens the same page, showing only the code.

Should I upgrade/update my router? If yes, how can I do that?

Here is the picture showing the page that opens when I click anything on the first default router page.

[image: Router site]

Comment: Please read our FAQ.

Comment: What model is the router? This looks like corrupt firmware.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed it belongs to serverfault. The answer to the question to opene it with IE did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Internet Explorer to access the router.